# Getting last 2 folder names from folder path

Tags: c#, directory

how do I can get name of last 2 folders from folder path in C#?

Folder path for example: `C:\test\documents\pdf\example.pdf`

I want `documents\pdf` . What object or method do I need to use?

Edit:
So far I've tried `string currentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);`

But it returns the whole path when I only want last 2 directories. Adding `string Folder = Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory).Name;`

returns parent folder `documents` but not `documents/pdf`.

Comment: what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

One example:

```
var yourDir = "C:\\test\\documents\\pdf\\";

// Get a DirectoryInfo object representing C:\\test\\documents\\pdf:
var info = new DirectoryInfo(yourDir); 

// Get "documents\\pdf":
var combined = info.Parent.Name + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + info.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetDirectoryName and it will return the full path without the filename

```
string path = "C:/test/documents/pdf/example.pdf";    
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Then split path by '/' and take the last two elements of the array